# deleted cron tab file and need to recover it

Tags: cron

I ran crontab -r instead of crontab -e and deleted my crontab file. I didn't have a backup and new to recover the deleted file.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: the options to edit and remove shouldn't be right next to each other on the keyboard. Too easy a mistake to make for a quick typer.

Comment: that's exactly what happened to me.

Answer (score 9):

Try looking at /var/log/cron to see what has been running and then try to recreate the crontab  from that.  Its messy but you should be able to restore everything that had previously run.  Not so much luck for newer items though.  Good luck!

Comment: Great approach!

Answer (score 5):

First of all: Always make backups!

But, it is so easy to mix up `crontab -r` and `crontab -e`. I just did this myself.

That's what I did:

You can try to have a look at /var/log/cron and build your crontab again.

1. Have a look at the logfile
2. Take the first command and do `grep commandname1 /var/log/cron`
3. Figure out the systematic behind the times the command was run
4. Put that entry to your new crontab
5. execute `cat /var/log/cron | grep -v commandname1`. This will exclude the command1 that you already covered.
6. Take the next command and grep for it
7. Figure out the systematic behind the times the second command was run
8. put that entry to your new crontab
9. execute `cat /var/log/cron | grep -v commandname1 | grep -v commandname2`
10. Repeat until you covered all commands

Now you should also execute the grep on older cronlogs to find out jobs that might be run only once in a month.

Comment: On Ubuntu at least (not sure about other platforms using anacron/Vixie cron) the log is stored in `/var/log/syslog/*`.

Comment: Before you accidentally delete something, always create a backup!

Answer (score 4):

### Script for full crontab recovery

I made a PHP script that does a full recovery of your crontab, based on the log.

It outputs a single instance of every cron command run by the user for the last week.

I put it here

https://github.com/dangreenisrael/recover_crontab

Here is a sample output:

```
perl ~/sorttv/sorttv.pl

/usr/local/bin/flexget

bash ~/scripts/sort_sports.sh

~/scripts/play_recently_added.sh
```

Comment: Why was this given -1? It's a direct answer to the question.

Comment: I have been using your script. Amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: The PHP script does not with properly for commands containing closing parenthesis. Fixed and ported to bash: `zgrep -F "($USER) CMD (" /var/log/syslog* | cut -d\( -f3- | sort -u | while read cmd ; do echo ${cmd::-1} ; done`

Answer (score 2):

Ugh can't post a comment on the original question, but a co-worker just showed me a great tool: make an alias in whatever `.profile` you use for `crontab` to be `crontab -i`. The `-i` flag asks for confirmation before deleting.

So, if you do `crontab -e` it will proceed to edit as usual, but if you accidentally do `crontab -r` you are greeted with a confirmation prompt.

Comment: That doesn't help with the immediate problem...

Comment: Thank you. This is a valuable action that may help prevent accidental delete of crontab in future.

Answer (score 1):

You've got options, but none are particularly pretty. In case you haven't thought of it, if you've got a recent version on a development machine, you can copy it from there ... I only say that because I often forget about copies that may be on other machines, so I assume that you've already tried that.

If your file is too heavily customized to make simply rebuilding it practical, you can always try some low-level forensics. Try googling for tutorials based around [sleuthkit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/) and UFS Explorer. People using these tools find widely varying degrees in terms of ease of use and success rates, so as usual, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. It's time to start to backup this important file (with all others in /etc /var/spool /home...).